# Disable the check box in the file manager?

Tags: pantheon-files

Sometimes I have accidentally deleted files or folder (using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>) without realizing that they were selected while I was deleting another file. Is it possible to disable that check box in the upper left of the file or folder's icon?

Comment: Hopefully things will be improved by Juno release, but I do not see how the checkbox emblem is a problem per se.  The file accidentally deleted could have been selected in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I usually press an Esc key when I am working with large number of folders or files and want to make sure that I only have 1 selected.
If you press Esc, then all highlights are reset and you can select whichever file you want. You can get used to it very quickly, took me 1 file sorting session to master it :)